# Bind Sharepoint list data in gridview

Tags: csom, gridview

I have two SharePoint two lists- A and B.
A has two columns- Id and People(Person or Group).
B has three columns - Id(lookup from A list),name,email.
In list A, a single item can have multiple person or group in the People column.The requirement is to fetch the email address of the people and bind it in individual rows of the gridview.

I have taken the following approach.But it makes the application very slow.Please help me with another approach.

```
        public List<EmailTool> GetData(string Id)
        {
        List<EmailTool> results = new List<EmailTool>(); 

        using (var clientContext = this.CreateClientContext())
        {
            #region A
            List A= clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("A");

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = string.Format("<View>"+
                "<Query>"+
                "<Where>"+
                "<Eq>"+
                "<FieldRef Name='Id'/> " +
                 "<Value Type='Integer'>{0}</Value>"+
                "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>"+
                "</Query>"+
                "</View>",Id);

            ListItemCollection nomItems= A.GetItems(query);
             clientContext.Load(A);
            clientContext.Load(nomItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem item in nomItems)
            {

                FieldUserValue[] nom = (FieldUserValue[])item["People"];

                foreach(FieldUserValue it in nom)
                {
                    EmailTool tool = new EmailTool();
                    tool.Name = it.LookupValue;                        
                    tool.EmailAddress = it.Email;                        
                    results.Add(tool); 
                }                    

            }
            #endregion A
            #region B
            List B= clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("B");
            CamlQuery queryB = new CamlQuery();
            queryB.ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where>" +
                                    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Id' LookupId='TRUE'/>" +
                                    "<Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value></Eq>" +
                            "</Where></Query></View>",Id);

            ListItemCollection nomItems1 = B.GetItems(queryB);
            clientContext.Load(B);
            clientContext.Load(nomItems1);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem item in nomItems1)
            {
                EmailTool tool1 = new EmailTool();
                tool1.Name = item["name"].ToString();
                tool1.EmailAddress = item["email"].ToString();
                    results.Add(tool1);
            }
            #endregion 

        }
        return results;

    }
```

After this binding the gridview with the values.The email address does come in  individual rows but it takes a lot of time.